# How to properly add an OnClick handler on Blazor RenderFragment CodeBehind

Tags: asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

As part of my project's specific need, I have to use render fragments on Blazor Code Behind (.cs file). Using the code below, I am able to render a button properly, however the @onclick handler seems to not be working or getting hit.

How do I properly add an onclick in a renderfragment builder?

```
RenderFragment template = builder =>
{
    builder.AddMarkupContent(1, $"<button class='btn btn-success' @onclick='() => OnToastClick({toastDetail.Key})'>{toastDetail.Key}</button>");
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AddMarkupContent()` adds *HTML* markup, it does not parse Razor content.

The best I could come up with:

```
RenderFragment template(IComponent owner, ToastDetail toastDetail)
{
    return builder =>
    {
        builder.OpenElement(1, "button");
        builder.AddAttribute(2, "class", "btn btn-success");
        builder.AddAttribute(3, "onclick",
            Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback.Factory.Create(owner, 
               () => OnToastClick(toastDetail.Key)));
        builder.AddContent(4, toastDetail.Key);
        builder.CloseElement();
    };
}
```

and then you can use it like

```
  @template(this, toastDetail)
```

Comment: @enet no this is not a miracle, as this is also on Blazor's Advanced Documentation. Tho I can't share to you my codebase, but you can get a similar one working by following this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/advanced-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: @enet the documentation link above puts the code on the Razor file, but you can also put in on your Code Behind / .cs file.